# Формула PHP конвертация градусов Цельсия в Фаренгейта

Tags: php

Помогите написать формулу по переводу градусов Цельсия в градусы Фаренгейта ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function convert($celsius)
{
    return ($celsius * 9/5) + 32;
}
```

Вот самый простой вариант

```
echo convert(100);
```

А дальше уже сами подгоняйте как вам надо.